# using sed to change particular parts of expression pattern

Tags: regex, sed

How can I change all strings in the file, which have the pattern: lowercase sequences of letters separated by one underscore and after last sequence are parentheses. I need change it to sequences, which are not
separated by underscore and any letter after underscore is changed to uppercase letter?

For example: `this_is_my_task()` change to `thisIsMyTask()`. I need to do it with sed.

But the program should not change string like: `this_is____my_task()`, because there are 4 underscores in a row.

Program should not change these strings: `___this_is_my_task()` or, because of there are underscores in the beginning of the first string.

I have tried this: `sed -r 's/([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)\(\)/\1\u\2()/' file.c`, but this will change it only to `this_is_myTask()`

Comment: Consider reformatting into multiple  paragraph/code blocks. Also it's not clear what are the separators in ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's{\b[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)+\(\)}{$&=~s/_([a-z])/\u$1/gr}ge' file.c
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8DkoEN) and the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzmiHE/1/), it matches

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[a-z]+`  - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:_[a-z]+)+` - one or more occurrences of `_` and 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `\(\)` - a `()` substring.

Once there is a match, the match value (`$&`) is replaced using `_([a-z])` pattern (`_` and then a lowercase letter in Group 1) that is replaced with the uppercase letter (`\u$1`).

With `sed`, you may use

```
sed -E ':a; s/\b([a-z][A-Za-z]*)_([a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*\(\))/\1\u\2/; ta' file.c
```

Or

```
sed -E ':a; s/\b([[:lower:]][[:alpha:]]*)_([[:lower:]]+(_[[:lower:]]+)*\(\))/\1\u\2/; ta' file.c
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/xIXHlX)

**Details**

- `:a` - sets the label with name `a`
- `s/\b([a-z][A-Za-z]*)_([a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*\(\))/\1\u\2/` - replaces

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `([a-z][A-Za-z]*)` -  Group 1: a lowercase letter followed with 0+ letters
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `([a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*\(\))` - Group 2:

    - `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase letters followed with
    - `(_[a-z]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of underscores and then 1+ lowercase letters and then followed with
    - `()` - a `()` substring

  with the Group 1 and  Group 2 values with the first char in Group 2 turned to upper
- `ta` - on a successful replace, jumps to label `a` position.

Comment: but this will also format string like this_is_my____task(), where i have four  underscores in a row. I need program will format only strings separated by one underscore. I correct this information in a question. sorry

Comment: @Student That is a minor tweak in the regex. See updated answer.

Comment: how to change expression, so it will not remake strings which have uppercase letters in first sequence or which have underscores in the beginning? I added examples in the problem description

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew this will remake string ```this_is_my_task()``` to ```thisIs_my_task()``` instead of ```thisIsMyTask()```

Comment: @Student Right, as there will be uppercase letters after the first replacement. So, you can't get any better with `sed` than https://ideone.com/xIXHlX

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that was the last question.